# FK to table with non-unique values via a on commit refreshing materialized view?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, oracle-11g, materialized-view, referential-integrity

I would like to create a FK to a table without unique values. So I cannot create a simple FK. [to clarify, the parent table has duplicates - dont ask why, not in my control ]

I tried creating a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW UniqueView
REFRESH ON COMMIT 
AS SELECT distinct currency from currencies
```

.. and then creating a FK to UniqueView. This works however, I cannot use ON COMMIT refresh because "distinct" function is used.

I would like the materialized view to be always up to date with the underlying table.

Any other methods of achieving this? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the **parent table** has duplicate rows, or the **child/FK table**?

Comment: Why not add a `currencies` table?

Comment: I think what @ypercubeᵀᴹ meant is you should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) your database

Comment: @Oreo, sorry, yes, the parent has duplicates. There is a reason for it, suffices to say that this is how it will stay and I have no control over that.

Comment: Why not create a new table with just the distinct values to use as a foreign key so you can have more normalized data?

Comment: @JoeW I do not have such flexibility. that one table with duplicates, must be the authoritative source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `GROUP BY`.

```
create table t1 (c1 varchar2(3), c2 number);
insert into t1 values ('EUR', 100);
insert into t1 values ('EUR', 200);
insert into t1 values ('USD', 150);
commit;

select * from t1;
C1          C2
--- ----------
EUR        100
EUR        200
USD        150

create materialized view log on t1 
  with rowid (c1) including new values;

create materialized view v1
refresh fast on commit as
select c1 from t1 group by c1;

select *from v1;
C1
---
EUR
USD

insert into t1 values ('CHF', 180);
commit;

SQL> select * from v1;
C1
---
EUR
USD
CHF
```